# How to upgrade ram in arduino?

Tags: arduino, ram, arduino-uno

I have an Arduino Uno which has 16MB RAM. I want to upgrade its ram (e.g 128 MB ) to store larger programs. Is this possible?

Actually I have tried storing datas in an external SD cards but using ram boosts the performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I start by supposing you are talking about the flash memory size and that you are actually meaning kilobytes not megabites.
The ram and storage are actually built in the microprocessor so you cannot "upgrade them" but you can swap it out with an equivalent with just more ram like the ATmega1284P which is basically the same but it has 128 KB of programmable flash and 16 KB of ram.
A different solution could be to add ram chips outside and access the through the code.